# JQuery Вызов функции из другого файла

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

Есть два js файла file1.js и file2.js.Подключаются в той же последовательности.

**File1.js**

```
'use strict';
function func1(){
    //some code
}

function func2(param1){
    func1();
    //some code
}

function func3(param1){
    //some code
}
```

**File2.js**

```
'use strict';
$(function () {

    $('.btn').click(function (e) {
        var t=$(e.target);
        func2(t);
    });

    $('.btn2').click(function (e) {
        func3(e);
    });

}
```

Получаю следующие ошибки:

*//file2.js*

func2 is not defined.

func3 is not defined.

*//file1.js*

func3 is defined but never used.

Где моя ошибка?

Comment: У вас в файле **File1.js** не используется обертка *(IIFE)* для функций `func2` и `func3`? Также убедитесь, что файл **File1.js** успешно загружен.

Comment: Зачем эта конструкция `$(function () {}`?

Comment: В том то и дело, оборачивать не надо. Попробуйте в консоли написать `window.func2` после загрузки страницы. Если выдаст `undefined`, то либо **File1.js** не загружается, либо у Вас ошибки синтаксические, либо есть обертка в **File1.js** над `func2`.

Comment: Это магия! Попробуйте создать пример, который бы воспроизводил проблему. Например, на https://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

В начале File1.js объявите функции глобально

```
window.func2 = func2;

window.func3 = func3;

//Ваш код
```